# Cascade file name changes on links in Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, symbolic-link, filenames, automatic-update

When making a link in Windows 7, is there a way to have name changes cascade to all links of the file?

So if I have a file called: `Interest.PDF` and make a few links in other folders, but then I later rename it to `Compound Interest.PDF` it's frustrating because the name change doesn't cascade to links.

Answer (score 1):

Short Answer: No. Symbolic Links point to a path. A hardlink might be your solution in a way. Hardlinks point to the inode addresses, which will still point to the file but the name will not update for the hardlink.[Read more Here](http://ipggi.wordpress.com/2009/09/07/windows-file-junctions-symbolic-links-and-hard-links/)

Otherwise you would have to write a script to traverse through the drive and find all links and update.